# php redirects and %s

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to update the search feature for the website bwa.org. Right now the find a writer function is not working. if you go [here](http://www.bwa.org/main/find-a-writer/) and search for "phil" or any of our other writers you will get the proper results but they contain the wrong hyperlinks. Clicking on the user's name or "view full profile" should take them to the back end wordpress user screen where employers/searchers can get a more complete view of their profile. Currently these hyperlinks take you to a list of every post they've written or commented on.

I think I've narrowed the problem down to this block of code:

```
$url = '/author/'.$res->user_nicename;

printf('<div class="user" id="user-%s" style="margin-bottom:15px;clear:left;border-bottom:1px solid #dfdfdf;">

<span class="username"><a href="%s">%s</a></span>

<dl id="usersearch" style="margin:5px 0 0 20px;">

<dt>Summary:</dt><dd>%s</dd>

<dt>Specialty:</dt><dd>%s</dd>

%s

</dl>

<p style="clear:left;padding-left:20px;">View <a href="%s">%s\'s full profile</a></p>

</div>',

$res->ID,

"/main".$url,

$res->display_name,

$summary,

$specialty,

(isset($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['city']) ? sprintf('<dt>City: </dt><dd>%s</dd>',$city) : ''),

"/main".$url,

$res->display_name);

}

echo '<p style="clear:left; padding-top:45px">Would you like to <button value="search again" onclick="window.location=\'/main/find-a-writer/\'"/>Search Again</button>?</p>';

}
```

I think the issue is the %s refers to the string that links to all their post data. I've read around on some other questions about how %s is just a placeholder for a string but I'm not sure where the string is assigned. Above is the first time it appears in the code. does anyone know how I can reassign the %s placeholder?

additional php code featuring $result:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($q); 


$results = $wpdb->get_results($q);

if (count($results) > 0) {

foreach ($results as $res) {

    $q2 = "SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key IN ('wpum_specialty', 'wpum_City', 'wpum_summary', 'last_name', 'first_name') AND user_id = ".$res->ID;

    $res2 = $wpdb->get_results($q2);

    $summary = '';

    $keywords = '';

    $software = '';

    $specialty = '';

    foreach ($res2 as $r2) {

        switch ($r2->meta_key) {

            case 'wpum_summary':

                $summary = $r2->meta_value;

                break;

            case 'wpum_City':

                $city = $r2->meta_value;

                break;

case 'wpum_specialty':

$specialty = $r2->meta_value;

break;

        }

    }
```

the second block of code is the code immediately preceding my first php code.

Comment: i think your printf should be an sprintf

Comment: @mr.void I tried changing the printf to sprintf and now I get no results. just says "no results would you like to search again"

Answer (score 0):

I would try and use `sprintf()` as opposed to `printf()`.

```
$result = sprintf('<div class="user" id="user-%s" style="margin-bottom:15px;clear:left;border-bottom:1px solid #dfdfdf;">
    <span class="username"><a href="%s">%s</a></span>
    <dl id="usersearch" style="margin:5px 0 0 20px;">
        <dt>Summary:</dt>
        <dd>%s</dd>
        <dt>Specialty:</dt>
        <dd>%s</dd>
        %s
    </dl>
    <p style="clear:left;padding-left:20px;">View <a href="%s">%s\'s full profile</a></p>
</div>',$res->ID,"/main" . $url,$res->display_name,$summary,$specialty,(isset($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['city']) ? sprintf('<dt>City:</dt><dd>%s</dd>', $city) : ''),"/main" . $url,$res->display_name);

print $result;
```

Comment: I replaced my code above with yours and now I just get a "would you like to search again?" with zero search results. I think it is because $result is written in the code. See my edit for the code featuring $result

Comment: @A.Must15 - Sorry, I forgot to print the result.  Updated my answer.

Comment: I added the print $result like you talked about and now all the hyperlinks redirect to the homepage.

Comment: All I did was take your code and make it a sprintf().  So, it sounds like your URL isn't correct in some way.